# Can the flap on one wing be used to reduce a left turning tendency?

Tags: wing, stability, flaps

I fly a single engine Jabiru UL45 and it has a tendency to turn left during straight and level flight.

Is it possible, in order to reduce a "Heavy Wing" to slightly increase the degree of the flap on that wing?

Comment: So probably no aileron trim?  Is the ball centered?  Does it roll left at cruise power?  Is the wing fuel balanced?

Comment: You’re talking about a very small airplane whose CG placement left/right will be strongly affected by you being in the pilot seat.  Have you flown with a similar-sized passenger, or put some ballast sandbags in the right seat?  Would be interesting to know if it’s aerodynamic/rigging, or just weight distribution that is causing this.

Answer (score 5):

This is easily done if your plane has *trim tabs* on the wing. This is a small strip of metal attached to the trailing edge of the wing which you bend with pliers little by little on the ground until the plane flies straight and level with the aileron trim centered.

Answer (score 4):

If you can rig the flaps at the retracted position to a slight differential, while ***staying within the rigging tolerances*** yes you can tweak the flaps to correct a rolling tendency. So if flaps zero is zero +/- .5 degree, there's nothing stopping you from adjusting the right flap up to .5 degree up, and left up to .5 degree down, to correct a left wing heaviness.

This is done on commercial aircraft all the time. Provided you stay within the published tolerances.

Answer (score 0):

No, probably not.  Most aircraft are designed to deploy flaps symmetrically.  If your aircraft has aileron trim, use that.

Comment: Unfortunately Michael it does not have aileron trim

Comment: Then how about rudder trim?